# Seeing unexpected data on a shared pointer

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I'm trying to convert a `nlohmann::json` object to a `std::shared_ptr<char[]>`. I'm running into an issue where the data inside the shared pointer seems to have extra junk attached that i did not have in my original object.

The function below is not as condensed as it could be because I wanted to show what I am seeing in the debugger. The comments you see are values of the variables at that line. I don't understand where this `ÍýýýýÝÝÝÝÝ¡\x4\x1d'ýI` is coming from. What am I doing wrong here?

```cpp
// Incoming json: {"data":[100]}
std::shared_ptr<char[]> serializeJson(nlohmann::json& d) {
    std::string ds = d.dump();                                // '{"data":[100]}'

    std::shared_ptr<char[]> rd(new char[ds.size() + 1]);     // 'ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍýýýýÝÝÝÝÝ¡\x4\x1d'ýI'
    ds.copy(rd.get(), ds.size() + 1);                        // '{"data":[100]}ÍýýýýÝÝÝÝÝ¡\x4\x1d'ýI'

    return rd;
}
```

I believe the data inside the pointer has been modified because when I try to deseerialize the string with the function below I get an exception. I've attached the values to this snippet as well ...

```cpp
nlohmann::json deserializeJson(const std::shared_ptr<char[]>& d) {
    std::string p = d.get();                            // '{"data":[100]}ÍýýýýÝÝÝÝÝû¤¶¯´2'
    std::string e = p.substr(p.size()-10);              // 'ÝÝÝÝû¤¶¯´2'
    nlohmann::json nd = nlohmann::json::parse(p);       // kaboom! / Exception
    return nd;
}
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: How do you examine the contents, in the debugger? Perhaps it doesn't understand that you're really have a pointer to a string. And why do you need the `shared_ptr` instead of a plain `std::string`? What problem is that supposed to solve? Can't you just pass `ds.c_str()` to whatever low-level C function that needs the raw string?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm viewing these variables in CLIons debugger console. I know the actual data is corrupt because when I try to deserialize the data (with `nlohmann::json::parse`) an exception gets thrown. I'll add more context to the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
ds.copy(rd.get(), ds.size() + 1);
```

[std::string::copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/copy) does not copy a null terminator, so when you construct a string here:

```
std::string p = d.get();
```

You read past the end of the array and invoke undefined behavior. This probably could have been avoided by just using `std::string`; `std::shared_ptr<char[]>` is unusual.

Comment: Adding the null terminator to the end of the character array fixed it for me. Thank you